# Update mysql when a time in a table is reached

Tags: php, mysql, database

So, I'm using a script in php that adds a certain time in the future in a mysql database.
What I want to do now is, when that time is reached, I want to update the table, changing a value in the table.

I have no idea how to do this... Crons don't update fast enough for this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "crons don't update fast enough?" Do you need to do this more often than every minute?

Comment: You can specify the exact time the script should execute using a crontab, it sounds as if you didn't know that. Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: My script adds a value, a time to the database. A cron would update either on a set time, or something like every minute. This is not what I need. I want a script to execute the moment the server time is equal to the time that is in the database.

Comment: You could take a look at MySql Triggers, might be of use.

Comment: What is the purpose of the immediate update? Depending on the details, you could do the update the next time you retrieve that data after the specified time has passed.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL has an event scheduler. Similar to crontab but for MySQL. [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html)

Essentially what you would do is create an event with your PHP script. You would tell that event to execute at a specific time.

```
CREATE
    [DEFINER = { user | CURRENT_USER }]
    EVENT
    [IF NOT EXISTS]
    event_name
    ON SCHEDULE schedule
    [ON COMPLETION [NOT] PRESERVE]
    [ENABLE | DISABLE | DISABLE ON SLAVE]
    [COMMENT 'comment']
    DO event_body;

schedule:
    AT timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...
  | EVERY interval
    [STARTS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]
    [ENDS timestamp [+ INTERVAL interval] ...]

interval:
    quantity {YEAR | QUARTER | MONTH | DAY | HOUR | MINUTE |
              WEEK | SECOND | YEAR_MONTH | DAY_HOUR | DAY_MINUTE |
              DAY_SECOND | HOUR_MINUTE | HOUR_SECOND | MINUTE_SECOND}
```

Answer (score 0):

make a script and use some browser extension to refresh page :> nah, just a joke. Sorry, weekend starts now! :) cronjobs should to the trick. I think You have missed something.. or question missing some info.

Comment: You should really read whole comments.. :) "nah, just a joke" and see my nice sarcasm-smiley-face.